# Flashing screen and blinking underscore at boot

Tags: debian

After an `aptitude safe-upgrade` my laptop doesn't boot any more.

I recorded [this video](http://clients.tourvista.co.uk/vt/zip/tmp/debian-boot.mp4) of the boot process.

I have access to tty1, and from there I can run `startx` which works without a problem.
Here is the output:

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.1.0 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root ro quiet
Build Date: 11 August 2015  10:51:15AM
xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1.1 (http://www.debian.org/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
   Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
   to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
   (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
   (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.2.log", Time: Fri Aug 28 15:55:04 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

I thought that the problem could be de DM. Here is `/var/lightdm/lightdm.log` output:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.14.2, UID=0 PID=1275
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.01s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading properties from config section SeatDefaults
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Could not run plymouth --ping: Failed to execute child process "plymouth" (No such file or directory)
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching process 1280: /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.01s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1280
[+0.35s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+0.35s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.35s] DEBUG: Session pid=1291: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Session pid=1291: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Session pid=1291: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm/data/lightdm
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Session pid=1291: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c7
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c7
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Session c7 is already active
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Session pid=1291: Greeter closed communication channel
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Session pid=1291: Exited with return value 0
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping; failed to start a greeter
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1280
[+0.51s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to
[+0.51s] CRITICAL: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Process 1280 exited with return value 0
[+1.52s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+1.52s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+1.52s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1
```

Notice the following line?

```
[+0.51s] CRITICAL: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
```

Mate uses Lightdm, so I removed and installed again, but that didn't make any difference.
Then I installed XLDE, which uses lxdm. Again, same problem: flashing screen and blinking coursor.

So it's nothing to do with X, because I can startx manually, and it's nothing to do with the desktop environment, as I have the same problem with both Mate and LXDE.

Anyone have a suggestion where should I begin to fix this problem?

Answer (score -2):

I've been looking into this and apparently the best way to solve this is to reinstall your entire OS.

Also, if you removed lightdm and installed it again, did you use `apt-get remove lightdm` or `apt-get purge lightdm`? Purging removes all configuration files as well.

Comment: You're suggesting a drastic action without any justification at all.

Comment: @garethTheRed I have looked all over the internet and this is the only method that I've found.